# Website loses connection to database intermittently

Tags: web-server, sql-server-2005, iis-6, windows-server-2003-r2, odbc

Every so often our website loses connection to the sql server and I receive the following errors:

"The following error: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection."

"The following error: A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The semaphore timeout period has expired.)"

"to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow connections."

"The following error: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached."

The connection loss normally occurs either late at night or very early in the morning, at random times. It would lose connection for exactly 10 minutes and then regain connection and all is well. During the day very rarely do we lose connection. We host our website using IIS6 and have a separate database server with SQL Server 2005 and the latest service packs. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: We need more info than a connection loss. What does the setup look like? Are the machines local to each other?

Comment: Is there a (badly configured) stateful firewall in between?

Comment: Would IIS happen to be recycling during that timeframe? I'm having the same problem with my website, but my IIS is setup as "AlwaysOn" in Azure...